# How do you detect physical screen flip on a 2-in-1 Notebook?

Tags: display, dell, xrandr, touchscreen

Making the display flip is pretty straight forward.  I detected that on my Dell Inspiron 15-7568 I have the following setup:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
```

Inverting and reverting are simple:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate inverted

xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal
```

**How do I detect the position of the display automatically so execute those commands?**

There must be a sensor in the display hinge that executes a hidden keyboard stroke or something like that.

Comment: After you flip the screen open or closed, do any messages about it appear when you run `dmesg | tail` ?